# APC does not show changes without restarting APACHE

Tags: php, apache, apc

I a using Apache2 to APC.

APC is storing and retrieving the data. However, whenever any changes occur, it does not show up the changes. I have `apc.stat=on` and its still the same.

FOllowing is my full APC configuration:

[image]

[image]